# Order Statistics Expectation and Variance

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

How would we go about finding the expectation and variance of the r$^{\text{th}}$ order statistic $X_{(r)}$ from a random sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ from a uniform distribution with density function

$$f(x)=1 \quad \quad \text{for} \ x \in (0,1)$$

and $f(x)=0$ otherwise?

Intuitively we can see the expectation is $\frac{r}{n+1}$ though I'm keen to see how that is derived from simply knowing the pdf of the distribution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose you know that
$$
a\Gamma(a) = \Gamma(a+1) \tag{1}
$$
and that
$$
\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1}\,dx = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}. \tag{2}
$$
From $(2)$, we get the probability density function of the Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\,dx=1.
$$
Now we want the first and second moments $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ of a random variable $X$ with this density.
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X) & = \int_0^1 x f(x)\, dx = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \int_0^1 x \cdot x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} \, dx \\  \\
& = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \int_0^1 x^{(\alpha+1)-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} \, dx. \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
The integral identity in $(2)$ holds if $\alpha$ is **any number at all**; therefore it holds for $\alpha+1$:
$$
\int_0^1 x^{(\alpha+1)-1}
 (1-x)^{\beta-1} \, dx = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma((\alpha+1)+\beta)}.
$$
It follows that the product in $(3)$ is
$$
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma((\alpha+1)+\beta)}
$$

So $\Gamma(\beta)$ cancels, and $(1)$ can be applied to change $\displaystyle\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$ to $\alpha$, and to change $\displaystyle\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma((\alpha+1)+\beta)}$ to $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}$.  Therefore the expression in $(3)$ simplifies to
$$
\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}.
$$
A similar technique differing only in details finds $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$.

Once you have $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$, you can use $\operatorname{var}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - (\mathbb{E}(X))^2$.  There's some algebraic simplifying to be done after that.  Remember that the variance should be symmetric in $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so if what you get is not symmetric, there's a mistake.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic .  The Beta distribution with parameters 
$r$ and $n+1-r$ has mean $\frac{r}{n+1}$ and variance ${\frac {r\, \left( n+1-r \right) }{ \left( n+1 \right) ^{2} \left( n+2
 \right) }}$.  Obtain these from the fact that $\int_0^1 t^a (1-t)^b\ dt = B(a+1,b+1) = \frac{a!b!}{(a+b+1)!}$.